# how to loop through group control buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

hi every one i have a form which contain a group control that have 47 button so, i want to loop through all the buttons and compare the text(button.text) of each button with textbox.text when a match is found then that button will be disable .. how to do this help please!!!!!

i am trying the following code .

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int seatno = int.Parse(textEdit1.Text.Trim().ToString());
    foreach (Button c in gp_seatss.Controls)
    {
        foreach (string str in Convert.ToString( c.Text))
        {
            if (str == Convert.ToString(seatno))
            {
                c.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: `foreach (string str in Convert.ToString( c.Text))`... `c.Text` I imagine would already be a string, converting it won't do anything, and then there aren't any strings in a strings to search. Even though fixing all of this may not fix your problem its still important to understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all `Button`s of `Groupbox` and set the condition:

```
foreach (Button btn in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (btn.Text == textBox1.Text)
        btn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void myMethod(Control.ControlCollection controls, string text)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
                ctrl.Enabled = ctrl.Text != text;

            if (ctrl.HasChildren)
                myMethod(ctrl.Controls, text);
        }
    }
```